# Bind ngModel to opposite value

Tags: angular

I fetch some data and set in checkbox and want to bind with [(ngModel)]. But according to logic I need to display a opposite value.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="!value" />
value: {{value}}
```

Why I must click twice for see the changes?

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3boip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solution 1

Define a getter/setter property for the opposite value:

```
get notValue(): boolean {
  return !this.value;
}

set notValue(val: boolean) {
  this.value = !val;
}
```

and bind `ngModel` to that property:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="notValue" />
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j77zc1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

---

### Solution 2

Split the `[(ngModel)]` binding:

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="!value" (ngModelChange)="value = !$event" />
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzozrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: loved solution 2